# horizontal navigation using nowrap

Tags: html, css

For a site I am building, which has horizontal navigation, I'm using `white-space: nowrap;`
with `display: inline-block;`. This works for aligning the `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` divs horizontally, the problem I am facing is if I add any other elements within these divs it pushes the parent div down about 300px as you can see here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFxCF/).

I can't figure out what the problem is. I can get around it by using `position: absolute;` for every child element but I feel that I shouldn't have to do that.

Full code below...

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;  padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:0;

}

.full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;    
}

#screen-1 {
    background: red;
}

#screen-2 {
    background: blue;
}

#screen-3 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

---

```
<div id="screen-1" class="full">
<h1>HELLO</h1>
</div>  

<div id="screen-2" class="full">

</div> 

<div id="screen-3" class="full">

</div>
```

Comment: If you want them side by side, why did you set 100% on width and height? Maybe I'm confused but I would maybe set the height but def. not width. Plus try `float: left`?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I understand, your not making a menu but an actual full page horizontal scrolling site. Right? If so read: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing! Everything works fine until I put another element within the .full div, unless I use `position: absolute;` which I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `position` property.
full code:

```
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    font-size:0;

}

.full {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size:16px;    
}

#screen-1 {
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0%;
}

#screen-2 {
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100%;
}

#screen-3 {
    background: yellow;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:200%;
}
.wrap {
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:1000%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="screen-1" class="full"><h1>HELLO</h1></div>
    <div id="screen-2" class="full"></div>
    <div id="screen-3" class="full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you'll have to use position absolute, unless possibly the container has a width of 300% and you float them.